# Convergence domain of $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n^x}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Exercise**: Determine the convergence domain if the following series $$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n^x}$$.
>
> **Solution**: If $x>1$ the series converge absolutely, if $0<x\leqslant 1$ the series converge but not absolutely, if $x\leqslant 0$ the series diverge.

**OP attempted resolution**:

I tried to solve it in the following way:
By the comparison(Weierstrass test) test:$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}|(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n^x}|\leqslant\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}|1\frac{1}{n^x}|=\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{n^x}|$.

Now applying the integral test:

$\int_\limits{1}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{n^x}|=\int_\limits{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^x}<\infty$ if $x<1$, which explains the first part of the solution.
However I cannot understand the second part of the solution "$0<x\leqslant 1$ the series converge but not absolutely" either why the series diverge when $x<0$, thought they diverged if $x\leqslant 1$.

**Questions**:

**1)** What am I doing wrong? How do I prove "$0<x\leqslant 1$ the series converge but not absolutely"? What does it mean?

**2)** According to solution "$x\leqslant 0$ the series diverge". Is not when $x\leqslant 1$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Dirichlet eta function (which is essentially the same function presented here), converges absolutely on $Re(x) > 1$. It turns out it still converges on $0 \lt x \le 1$, but only conditionally, meaning that in that small strip its counterpart $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}$ (the Riemann zeta function) diverges. Under conditional convergence, an expression, after rearranging of terms, can converge to an arbitrarily large number or even diverge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0< x \le 1$ the series converges by [Alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test) and diverges absolutely by comparison test with $\sum \frac1 n$.

For $x\le 0$ it diverges since $\lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n|\neq 0$.